# Will something bad happen if I finish the Master Core too slowly?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Spoilers because this question discusses the new final boss in Super Smash Bros. WiiU / 3DS.

> After defeating the Master Core, it turns into an object that looks like a smash ball that you hit repeatedly until you knock it off the stage. It doesn't seem like the boss attacks you at all during this stage. If you take too long to finish the boss at this point, can anything bad happen? Or could I, for example, leave the game running for half an hour at this point and then finish it without any penalty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Will "something bad happen"? Very much indeed.

> If you take longer than 40-50 seconds to finish off Master Core, it'll rise into the air and blast you with five Off Wave-like rings, each of which will KO you instantly. If you're still around afterwards, it'll self-destruct.

Comment: No kidding! I found this video confirming what you said (spoilers, of course): http://youtu.be/WXK0FDsSx-g

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on what Intensity level you're playing at.

> At Intensity 8.0 (and above, I'm assuming), after beating your shadow clone, the Master Core itself does not appear, but instead a maze appears, in which several weaker Master Core-like objects are present.  The timer is still going in this section.
>  I'm not sure what happens at the end of this part, I have not beaten it yet

This is on the Wii-U version, I don't own the 3DS version (yet).

Comment: I know from some of the Nintendo Direct videos that what this answer discusses is only available on the WiiU, and only on 1-player classic (not co-op).

Comment: I have to downvote this because the question is about phase Q, and you're talking about phase X.